# The name 'BankAccounts' does not exist in the current context

Tags: c#, c#-4.0

So I'm a beginner with c# experimenting with the Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel reference, and I've ran into an issue. Here's my main form:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{ 
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    public void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var BankAccounts = new List<Account>
        {
            new Account
            {
                ID = 345,
                Balance = 541.27
            },
            new Account
            {
                ID = 123,
                Balance = -127.44
            }
        };
    }

    public void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ThisAddIn.DisplayInExcel(BankAccounts, (Account, cell) =>
        // This multiline lambda expression sets custom processing rules  
        // for the bankAccounts.
        {
            cell.Value = Account.ID;
            cell.Offset[0, 1].Value = Account.Balance;
            if (Account.Balance < 0)
            {
                cell.Interior.Color = 255;
                cell.Offset[0, 1].Interior.Color = 255;
            }
        });

    }
}
```

Returns the error:

> The name 'BankAccounts' does not exist in the current context

I can't understand how this is happening, could someone please help me fix this and perhaps explain what's caused it?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: `BankAccounts` only exist within the scope of the method `Form1_Load`

Comment: Ah thank you, I see where I was going wrong. How would I make it so that `BankAccounts` can be used from a different class?

Comment: to use it from another class you have to either add a getter function or make the variable public.

Answer (score 1):

Have BankAccounts as a class field:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{




private List<Account> BankAccounts;

public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();
}

public void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    BankAccounts = new List<Account>
    {
        new Account
        {
            ID = 345,
            Balance = 541.27
        },
        new Account
        {
            ID = 123,
            Balance = -127.44
        }
    };
}

public void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ThisAddIn.DisplayInExcel(BankAccounts, (Account, cell) =>
    // This multiline lambda expression sets custom processing rules  
    // for the bankAccounts.
    {
        cell.Value = Account.ID;
        cell.Offset[0, 1].Value = Account.Balance;
        if (Account.Balance < 0)
        {
            cell.Interior.Color = 255;
            cell.Offset[0, 1].Interior.Color = 255;
        }
    });

}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Make BankAccounts a variable within Form1 scope (more on [scopes](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms973875.aspx)):

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{ 
    // when placed here, any method in Form1 can access it
    List<Account> BankAccounts;

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    public void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        BankAccounts = new List<Account>
        {
            new Account
            {
                ID = 345,
                Balance = 541.27
            },
            new Account
            {
                ID = 123,
                Balance = -127.44
            }
        };
    }

    public void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ThisAddIn.DisplayInExcel(BankAccounts, (Account, cell) =>
        // This multiline lambda expression sets custom processing rules  
        // for the bankAccounts.
        {
            cell.Value = Account.ID;
            cell.Offset[0, 1].Value = Account.Balance;
            if (Account.Balance < 0)
            {
                cell.Interior.Color = 255;
                cell.Offset[0, 1].Interior.Color = 255;
            }
        });

    }
}
```

Comment: The contextual keyword 'var' may only appear within a local variable declaration

Comment: I've tried using this exact code, however it seems to return the same error.

Comment: `var` can only be used when declaring variables in method scope. Change it to `List<Account> BankAccount;`.